# Como especificar el segundo item de una div que contiene varios elementos 'link' o '<a></a>'?

Tags: html, nodejs, selectores, puppeteer

Quiero usar un selector que me lleve al segundo item dentro de los elementos `a` o links que contiene esta `div`, al ejecutar mi codigo, en  `node.js` el programa encuentra el primer elemento que se encuentra en esta `div`, ¿pero como puedo aplicar un selector sobre el segundo elemento?

```
  "div#links.panel-collapse.in.collapse.show > div.panel-body > a.dropdown-item"
```

Estoy utilizando `puppeteer` de desde `nodejs` y requiero el uso de este selector en el segundo item para navegar en esta pagina por medio de un bot.

Comment: podrías hacer uso de nth-child: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp. El enlace es de un selector css, pero creo que debería funcionar.

Comment: Prueba cambiando la última parte a `a.dropdown-item:nth-child(2)`

Answer (score 0):

that's how I solved it, clicking console.

```
await page.evaluate( () => {
  const elem1 = document.querySelectorAll('links')[1] as HTMLElement;
  elem1.click();
}
```